# Alarm manager for starting a notification every 15 minutes

Tags: android, service, notifications, alarmmanager

BootCompletedReceiver runs a background service at the boot time, so the notification for the birthday is in the notification bar during runtime. When I remove notification from the notification bar, I expect to see it 15 minutes after that, but I don't, it appears randomly.

What's wrong with my code?

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, BirthdayNotifyService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
    setAlarm(context, pendingIntent);
}

private void setAlarm(Context context, PendingIntent pendingIntent) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 2, pendingIntent);
}


public class BirthdayNotifyService extends Service {

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    createNotifications();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private void createNotifications() {
    // Fetching contacts from the Contacts application
    ArrayList<MyContact> contactsList = BirthdayDataFactory.getContacts(this);
    // Going trough the contacts list and creating notifications for each contact that has birthday
    for (int i = 0; i<contactsList.size(); i++) {
        if(contactsList.get(i).hasBirthday()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
            // Creating a notification builder
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                    (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification)
                            .setContentTitle("Birthday Notifier")
                            .setContentText(contactsList.get(i).getName() + " has a Birthday today!")
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            // Creating a notification manager
            NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
            manager.notify(i, builder.build());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> "When I remove notification from the notification bar, I expect to see
>   it 15 minutes after that"

If this is what you want to happen, you do not need a service or a repeating alarm.

The jist of what you should do is use .setDeleteIntent(Intent intent) on your NotificationBuilder, passing in an intent that sets an alarm to run the notification code again in 15 minutes, which looks like this, rather than what you currently have in setAlarm():

```
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 1000*60*15, pendingIntent);
```

---

What you are currently doing in your code is as follows:

**`context.startService(serviceIntent);`**
Starts the service immediately which displays the notifications

**`setAlarm(context, pendingIntent);`**

Sets an alarm which displays the notifications, triggering immediately and every 2 minutes thereafter

---

I suggest reading up more on what exactly each method/class you're using does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `alarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES` instead of `1000 * 60 * 2`